# Illustration of the search for the right proportion that symbolizes the golden ratio.

Tags: reference-request, reference-works

My teacher asked us to illustrate, using a scientific poster the search for the right proportion that symbolizes the golden ratio. The problem statement is the following:

What about today that aspiration to the agreement between reason and things, between reason and men? What correspondence, quantifiable or not, what models , digital or not, suggest to us that the balance is still possible and that it is worthwhile to pursue harmony in all its forms and in all its forms? I thought to illustrate the harmony in the nature thanks to the golden ratio. I thought that relpies to the the question. In my Internet browsing, I did not find very useful informations and pictures to take for the poster. Have you any suggestions to make a good poster with good and clear informations and pictures to use for my poster? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Vitruvian Man, the Nautilus shell spiral, flowers (sunflower closeups are impressive), pinecones, Mandelbrot renderings... all have Fibonacci or Golden Ratio characteristics.

Comment: @Khadija: I highly suggest Da Vinci's _Vitruvian Man_. He is, after all, a perfect example of a Renaissance man.